# Error In OpenCV Setup In Eclipse

Tags: android, opencv

I try to setup OpenCV in eclipse  in windows 7 and when  I try to run an openCV example on eclipse I have an error like that
 21:24:25 **** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle ****
"C:\Users\omer\Downloads\android-ndk-r10c\ndk-build.cmd" all 
C:/Users/omer/Downloads/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk:209: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk

and I dont know how can I solve this problem. Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8`

Obviously API 19 is required.

So set your `minSdkVersion` to 19.

If using Gradle, then that will go to build.gradle file in your `app` directory.

Comment: it solve this problem but another problem occurs which is "C:\\Users\\omer\\Downloads\\android-ndk-r10c\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
C:/Users/omer/Downloads/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk:209: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be easier to use java wrapper of opencv instead of nativ one. Its called JavaCV. Here you have link how to add it to your project
[link](http://javacv4android.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-import-javacv-libraries-to.html)

Using this you will be able to simply use java without ndk and c/c++

Comment: can I use tihs library for making image processing in android?

Comment: You will be able to use java to use all the algorithms available in opencv

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to setup NDK for eclipse.[ndk download](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)